# How does Maven resolve sbt transitive dependencies? Is this Maven at all?

Tags: maven, sbt

I have a maven project that depends on several sbt project, which in turn depends on more projects. Are these transitive dependencies being resolved by maven? E.g. in packing of assemby jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this question with mine: How can you know what build tool was used in a dependency?

You can't unless the build tool leaves some files to let you *guess* what the build tool could have been. But still, they're just files that are generated as part of the publishing process so the other build tools could resolve dependencies.

That's the point of any build tool to let you integrate with the other build systems in a less troublesome way.

Maven requires `pom.xml` and an appropriate repository layout. sbt follows the rules while `publish`ing project artifacts to Maven repositories.

Ivy requires other files in repositories and sbt does generate them (by default).

Gradle plugs itself in to the game by following Maven's standard files and directory layout.

Read about `publish` task. You may want to consult [the official documentation of sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/documentation.html). Start with http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html.